# What do kendo parseNumber does with "NaN"?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2

Where can I see the code of the Telerik's Kendo Angular `parseNumber` function?

I seems it parses OK "Infinity" but does not parse "NaN", transforming to `null`...

Why? And how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, after some research in the code, that the key point is here:

[image]

```
if (exponentRegExp.test(number)) {
    number = parseFloat(number.replace(symbols.decimal, POINT));
    return isNaN(number) ? null : number;
}
```

knowing that:

```
?parseFloat("Infinity")
>Infinity
?parseFloat("NaN")
>NaN
?parseFloat("null")
>NaN
?parseFloat("blabla")
>NaN
```

I would prefeer, however, that instead of `null` to have `NaN`..